# Add custom routes to GKE pods

Tags: networking, routes, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I have a system where pods attempt to access a specific subnet via a gateway VM.

The topology looks something like this:

Pod A (10.10.0.2) -> Gateway VM (10.10.0.1 - 11.11.0.1) -> VM B (11.11.0.2)

Basically Pod A should be able to ping and interact with VM B. The cloud router allows VMs in my network to communicate but not specific pods unless the "hostNetwork: true" is specified (which I do not want to specify).

My question is how can I either force the pod to use the cloud router specified routes or add a custom route to the pod in a VPC-native cluster.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is your network topology ? Is your Cloud router between the VPC and an onprem network via VPN/Interconnect or is it Between two VPC's ?

The reason probably your pod is not able to reach VM B has to do with the VPC native cluster. When you have a VPC native cluster, the Pod IP range is secondary and different from the node IP range (Hence why when you configure HostNetwork it works). So you have to make sure the secondary ranges are also advertised via the Cloud Router.

Comment: I reached the same conclusion today and managed to make this work by enabling masquerading. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found a solution using the ip-masq-agent. In this case masquerading is disabled by default which means pod traffic leaves the cluster with a different IP address than the gateway subnet, as a result there is no routing through the gateway.

Enabling the ip-masq-agent configuration changes the pod IP address to the node IP address which is in the same subnet as the gateway and enables routing to take place.

Source: https://sreeninet.wordpress.com/2019/08/11/gke-with-vpn-networking-options/

This allowed pods to communicate through the gateway to other subnets without occupying the node host network directly.